# Sending Ether failing in smart contract failing

Tags: ethereum, call, solidity, send, transfer

I am learning  solidity and testing out accepting payment of a fixed amount using a smart contract.
I took this code from a tutorial website and im testing it in Remix.

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.7;

contract DonateContract {

  address payable public owner;
   
  //contract settings
  constructor() {
    owner = payable(msg.sender);
  }

  //public function to make donate
  function donate() public payable {
    (bool success,) = owner.call{value: 10000 wei}("");
    require(success, "Failed to send money");
  }
}
```

I want to transfer a fixed amount of 10000 WEI.
The message sender has a 100 ETH balance.
The owner is just an address, not a contract.

It gives the error "Failed to send money" every time.

Comment: is the contract DonateContract filled with eth?

Comment: it may not have enough eth to send

Comment: I want the ETH to come from the msg.sender and be received by the owner.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that by sending a fixed wei amount to the owner, you do not know if the contract will have enough balance to make the transaction. To do so, I would suggest maybe transferring the msg.value amount, so that you ensure that all the eth sent to the contract is redirected to the owner's balance. It would be something like this:

```
(bool success,) = owner.call{value: msg.value}("");
```

Hope you find this information useful :)

Comment: And how does the msg.sender send the ETH to the contract when calling the function?

Comment: By sending a value to the message. It is a manual process and you can not interact with an address ether balance directly. Remix IDE let's you send a value when sending a transaction. You can check it.

Comment: Ah perfect. I was misunderstanding how the value transfer worked. If you post an answer explaining that the msg.sender must suppy the Ether in the value section of the request. The contract then sends the value received to the owner.

Comment: That’s right. Msg.value takes all the ether sent to the transaction.

Answer (score 0):

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.7;
contract transfertot{
    //address  public address1=0x5B38Da6a701c568545dCfcB03FcB875f56beddC4; it is owner address sample
    address  public address2=0x4B20993Bc481177ec7E8f571ceCaE8A9e22C02db;  // it is reciever address sample
        address payable public owner;
        constructor()payable {
            owner=payable(msg.sender);
        }
        
    uint public msgvalue=msg.value;//contract value 
         uint  balance1;//owner balance
         uint  balance2;//reciever balance
         uint[]  balance1arr;
         uint[]  balance2arr;


        function transfer1(address payable  _address,uint _priceGwei)payable public  {
        require(_priceGwei<=(msgvalue/10**9),"balance is less than msgvalue");//working in gwei
            _address.transfer(_priceGwei*10**9);
            balance1=owner.balance/(10**9);
            balance2=address2.balance/(10**9);
            balance1arr.push(balance1);
            balance2arr.push(balance2);
            msgvalue-=_priceGwei*10**9;
        }
    function ownerbalancearr()public view returns(uint[] memory){
        return balance1arr;
    }
     function recieverbalancearr()public view returns(uint[] memory){
        return balance2arr;
    }
}
//when you want to deploy add some gwei to value in deploy and run transactions panel`
//the contract value is differ from owner value
//you can  check the`enter code here` output in this code
//good day to you`
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).